# Aspose.cells custom date formatting irrespective of OS date format

Tags: excel, aspose, aspose-cells

I am currently using aspose.cells for .Net and need to set a custom format a date based on the current language being used in our app. Issue is, we are setting the format via code below, but if the system(OS) date format is different, our custom formatting goes for a toss and the excel displays the date in the system(OS) format. Is there a workaround for this? Below is the code:

```
var dateStyle = dataWorksheet.Cells.GetCellStyle(startRowNumber, column);

            dateStyle.Custom = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
            var dateRange = dataWorksheet.Cells.CreateRange(startRowNumber, column, dataTable.Rows.Count + 1, 1);

            dateRange.SetStyle(dateStyle);
```

Also tried the solution [here](https://www.aspose.com/community/forums/thread/394567/cell-date-format-globalization-issue.aspx), but, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

@Gautam, 
Please note, the statement CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern returns a pattern which is an Excel's built-in format (M/d/yyyy) therefore setting it to a cell (or range of cells) as custom format will auto convert the format to built-in, which will change according to the locale of the machine where the spreadsheet is going to be loaded. I would suggest you to use the custom pattern as mm/dd/yyyy which would yield similar result but the format will not change according to the locale. Please check following piece of code as well as the attached snapshot showing the Format Cell dialog.

C#

```
var book = new Workbook();
var sheet = book.Worksheets[0];
var dateStyle = sheet.Cells.GetCellStyle(0, 0);

dateStyle.Custom = "mm/dd/yyyy";//CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US").DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern; //represents M/d/yyyy
var dateRange = sheet.Cells.CreateRange(1, 0, 10, 1);
dateRange.SetStyle(dateStyle);
dateRange.PutValue("26-Sep-2014", true, false);
book.Save(dir + "output.xlsx");
```

[image]

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*